# Deleted files showing in windows search

Tags: windows-10, search, start-menu

I uninstalled VS 2015 professional but for some reason the cmd tools still appear in search results when searching for cmd or prompt. However, these search results are broken, clicking on the item or right clicking it will do nothing.

What's even more funny, is that VS 2017 cmd tools are not shown although these are found in VS Start menu folder and can be browsed normally.

I tried re-indexing from **control panel** => **indexing options** => **advanced** => **troubleshooting** but nothing changed.

The problem at hand can be generalized (and is not restricted to VS cmd tools), it's about showing broken search results pertaining to non-existent files or programs.

Comment: Have you tried any junk cleaning tool like CCleaner etc.

Comment: yes, still the same.